# Terminal "osascript -e" commands

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, terminal

What commands can be used with the `osascript -e` argument?

I know of the command `osascript -e "set Volume x"` where x is 0-7.  Is there anything else I can use instead of `set` or `Volume`?  Or some documentation you could link me to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

osascript is a tool to execute AppleScript within a shell/script.

Here is Apple's introductory guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html

Additionally, you can open Script Editor.app (in /Applications/Utilities if your on OS X 10.11).  From the menu bar select Window > Library to browse library documentation.

Comment: so in order to run different `osascript` commands, I will have to manually make them and save them, then run it with the command?

Comment: You can run any AppleScript snippet you would like, ad-hoc or in a saved shell script.  Just substitute what is in between the quotation marks with your AppleScript snippet.  You can also use Script Editor to create little self-contained applications, scripts, commands, etc.  Give the guide a good look - it will answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Like "willWorkForCookies" said, instead of using "defaults write…" you can: . . . . . . . . . . osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1' . . . . . . . . . . which will directly change any System setting without re-log-in.